# Steady states and eigenvalues of equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

> [image]

I tried to solve the given problem above with the following code.

```
syms y r K theta
eqn = r*y*(y/theta - 1)*(1-y/K) == 0;
S=solve(eqn, y)

derivative = diff(eqn)

eigenvalue1 = subs(derivative, y, theta)
eigenvalue2 = subs(derivative, y, K)
eigenvalue3 = subs(derivative, y, 0)
```

Which prints that the steady states are: `0, theta, K`.
So I substituted these values for `y` in order to get the eigenvalues of the derivative, however I am unsure if this is the correct way of doing it. The eigenvalues are then:

```
eigenvalue1 =
 
-r*(theta/K - 1) == 0
 
eigenvalue2 =
 
-r*(K/theta - 1) == 0
 
eigenvalue3 =
 
-r == 0
```

Are these correct? And if so, how do I go about answering the last question of whether they are stable/unstable?

Comment: Well, the last sentence in your homework says "non-trivial (nonzero) steady states". So that already tells you that what you have is the trivial, i.e. all-zero solution. You'll need to find another. Also, for eigenvalues 1 and 2 to be zero, it's either `r==0`, or `K==theta`

Comment: @Adriaan So where am I going wrong? Is it when I write 

```
eigenvalue1 = subs(derivative, y, theta)
eigenvalue2 = subs(derivative, y, K)
eigenvalue3 = subs(derivative, y, 0)
```
or are my steady state values wrong?